"Was" vs. "is" in scientific technical writing
I just received reviews of my manuscript, and one of the reviewers wanted all of the "was" regarding individual observations derived from computational runs to be changed to "is."
From my perspective, results from experimentation (computation) were observed in the past, and describing what was observed in the past should use "was".
For example:
"Method A was better than method B for distinguishing...."
If this statement was changed to:
"Method A is better than method B for distinguishing...,"
it guarantees that Method A will be better than method B in the future, but as a scientist (physicist) you can only make statements about what was observed during the experiment, and not make statements about how something will work in the future.
I think I want to respond by saying the particular reviewer is wrong concerning statements about observations made during a past experiment (computational run).
Do you think this is a generational thing?

This question on the Academia SE may help.

In your example, comparing Method A to Method B, the use of was is observational. Changing was to is makes it a statement. Method A is better than Method B at sorting jelly beans.  The word 'is' makes this it an assertion that can be then defended by your supporting data. As you said 'is' applies to the future, other jelly bean sorting researchers should use Method A instead of B.
Physics is filled with 'is' statements. Force is the product of mass and acceleration. Changing that to a 'was' would sound odd because the passiveness of 'was' weakens the declarative value of the work. Was is like we thought A worked better than B, but your mileage may vary because 9 out of 10 dentists agree.
In the end, it depends on your confidence in the data. Is the experiment noisy and hard to replicate. Then maybe 'was' is pragmatic. 'Was' leaves wiggle room  that 'is' closes off entirely.

Results of your experiments should be reported in past tense ("Using method A, mean age was 46 years."), but the discussion of the implications of those results should be given in present tense ("This means that method A is better suited than method B for distinguishing...").
Here are the APA recommendations for verb tense: https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/grammar/verb-tense

Ben, your past-tense example is formulated poorly. Surely, the reason method A was used is something other than to obtain a mean age. Nor  is the mean age what did the using of method A. I’d suggest something more like The mean of the ages obtained using method A is 46 years. And note that this rewrite uses the past tense as you suggest (the experimental results were obtained in the past) and uses the present tense as the manuscript’s reviewer suggests (the mean age continues to be 46 years).

@PaulTanenbaum Your example is wrong! Correctly it would be: "The mean of the ages obtained using method A was 46 years." In experimental sciences, the results of every experiment are always in the past. Because only at that time did that method lead to that particular result. The same experiment, using the same method, will almost always lead to a different result when it is repeated. You will never run the same time on 100 m. You will never score the same result in an IQ test. The number of mistakes a worker makes during one hour will never be the same. And so on.

@PaulTanenbaum Also: "The mean age was 41.2 years for subjects ascertained by using Method II..." (https://www.jacionline.org/article/S0091-6749%2810%2900666-4/fulltext) = "Using Method II to ascertain subjects, mean age was 41.2 years." ;-)

Ben, I understand your view, but calling use of the present “wrong” is itself wrong. The data was (or, if you wish, were) collected. That definitely is in the past. But now the data exists  and it now has an average. If one checks that data’s average a century from now, it will still equal 46 years. Sure, if you collect further data, then that new sample could result in a different average. But the data reported in the sentence in question will always retain that one average of 46 years.

And, Ben, the fact that you can point to a published paper with an infelicitous wording certainly doesn’t make the wording advisable.

@PaulTanenbaum I don't get what you keep arguing about here. There is a clear rule. I linked to it. Your version is against the rules. What is there to discuss?

Ben, in the first place, you cite one style guide, not the U.S. Constitution. And second, the closest example it gives to your own sample has the form results showed, which is not the same as mean age was. But thirdly, what I find poorly formulated in your sample is distinct from the tense of to be, it’s the dangling participle. If you want to express a mathematical fact like (44+48)/2 = 46 in the past tense, that’s on you.

@PaulTanenbaum Please provide a style guide that doesn't recommend to report results in the past tense. And second, results showed is in the past tense just as mean age was is.

Ben, I don’t have any style guides at hand, but I can point you to a question at our sister site, Academia, where you’ll find an answer (with no fewer than 80 upvotes). See here for the details.

@PaulTanenbaum That answer uses past tense for the results: "The results obtained, shown in Fig. 3, clearly emphasize that the cell colonies grew faster on pink toothbrushes than green ones." (my emphasis) So it proves that I am right and you are wrong. Also, just because random people on the internet have this or that opinion about what tense to use, doesn't make them right. Please provide a style guide that clearly says to use present tense for experimental results. Unless you can, you are wrong. And please stop spamming this comment section. It is time to accept that you are mistaken.

Wow, Ben, you’re pretty juiced about this. Spam? I responded directly to your question/challenge.  Seems that intellectual openness isn’t on the table for you today. Not sure why you’re so invested in your being “right” and my being “wrong,” but whatever.

It's okay to "mean age", since it is the average of many age values.  "Mean of the ages" is not used, since "age" is the name of the measurement taken (variable, feature, attribute, etc).  In the biomedical space, I would still say "was" for results of a validation study for which results are assertive.    Results from observational studies are different from the laws of physics, where you can say "...acceleration of car A with much greater horsepower and less weight will be greater than the heavier car B with a weaker engine."
